# does a font on a server have to be linked in a specific way?

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to link a font from my server to my html document so that I can use this custom font.

what i wrote was

```
<style>
@font-face { font-family: font-name; src: url('http://servername.webitsitename.ca/fonts/font-name.otf'); }

.FindLocal {

    font-family: 'font-name';
    color: #0079cc;
}

</style>
```

Due to certain limitations, I cannot use an external CSS file, so it all has to be styled inside the html document. And this particular font is used by the company and they want it for the website, but for some reason it's not working. The landing page is being designed on a website that doesn't let me upload fonts (its quite difficult site to use tbh lol but company insists so...)

Any ideas as to why this isn't working? does it have to be like google's?

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans ? so fonts.websitename.ca/css?family=font-name ?

I also tried @import url(http://convio.cancer.ca/fonts/RockwellStd-Light.otf); within the style sheet but no luck.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you link it via HTML, this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence" />
```

That way you don't have to extend the stylesheet.

Comment: it's weird I tried doing that but it didn't work either, maybe i did something wrong. i'll try it again.

Comment: Are you sure your server is not blocking Google's server?

Comment: if i use google's font link it works fine but they don't have the font we use, its the one i have uploaded on our server that I want to use with "leadpages.net" i can't seem to get it to work like i do for google.

Comment: It could be that the permissions on your server do not allow serving up that filetype.

Comment: hmmm maybe not? It's weird because locally i can use it off of the server because the main website does. But I'm creating a landing page with leadpages, and it just refuses to work. I guess the server won't recognize it as a url? doesn't make sense to me but I guess i have no choice but to just use a google font.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can probably see it locally because you have it installed on your machine.  You may not be able to see it outside because the server is not serving it up.

Comment: that would make sense. I found a google font that is kinda similar to the one we're using. Hopefully higher ups approve lol.